# how to derive a base class from System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying modify the NearForums-CMS application and everything works fine except this class that extends WebViewPage.As shown:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Msupa.Web.Common.State;
using System.Web;
using Msupa.Localization;
using Msupa.Base;
using Msupa.Configurations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Msupa.Web.Common.Extensions;


namespace Msupa.Web.Common.UI
{
    public class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class
    {
        #region Initialization
        public BaseViewPage()
        {

        }
```

I have checked MSDN documentation and included all dependancies which in this case is "System.Web.Mvc;".
I keep getting this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'WebViewPage' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: You are correct there is no reason that this should not work, it is in the namespace, and you have included it correct. Did you ever find the problem?